# End task when access is denied (even when using cmd taskkill / powershell kill)

Tags: windows-11, uninstall, task-manager, kill, tasks

I have found a process running on my computer "rsEngineSvc.exe" and i want to uninstall this application from my laptop, meaning i must end the process to do so.
I have tried using taskkill in CMD and kill in powershell but it still pops up with the error message "The operation could not be completed" "Access is denied". (I'm on windows 11)

Comment: Why does "uninstall this application" require to "end the process to do so"? Usually you uninstall an application from Settings>Apps and it uninstaller takes care of it. This process is part of an Antivirus (Reason Antivirus or Reason Core Security) and it makes sense for an AV to protect its process from termination.

Comment: Likely, it is an antimalware app from Reason Software Company Inc. at https://www.reasonsecurity.com/ . If you don't want that app running, **then uninstall the suite, replacing it with another security package**. See https://howtoremove.guide/reason-security-engine-uninstall/ and https://www.uninstallgeeks.com/how-to-uninstall-reason-core-security-review-in-pc-windows-7-8-10-and-mac

Answer (score 0):

Most anti-virus programs have anti-kill protections on their processes. This protects them from being killed by malware.

The correct way to end the processes is to remove the software using the correct uninstallation method.

If this method is not working, most AV makers have uninstall utilities or guides for manual removal, but as you haven't told us you've tried uninstalling yet, you should start with that.